# How is $X(X^{\prime}X)^{-}X^{\prime}$ symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

For a matrix $X$, a generalized inverse of $X$ is any matrix $Y$ such that $XYX = X$. We use $X^{-}$ to indicate a generalized inverse of $X$.

Suppose $X$ is a matrix. $X^{\prime}$ denotes the transpose of $X$. Then clearly $X^{\prime}X$ is symmetric and has a generalized inverse that is symmetric [say $(X^{\prime}X)^{-}$] by a theorem I previously proved. This I follow.

This textbook I have then starts saying $X(X^{\prime}X)^{-}X^{\prime}$ is symmetric without any discussion as to why, and no previous theorems or lemmas seem to hint at this. Why is this the case?

[I am sorry if this isn't enough information to show my effort, but I am extremely lost as to why to think this is true.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was more obvious than I would've liked it to be, hah.

We have $$\left[X(X^{\prime}X)^{-}X^{\prime}\right]^{\prime} = \left(X^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}\left[(X^{\prime}X)^{-}\right]^{\prime}X^{\prime} = X\left[(X^{\prime}X)^{-}\right]^{\prime}X^{\prime}$$
and see [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306106/how-is-xx-primex-x-prime-symmetric#comment2653345_1306115).

Comment: Why $(X'X)^-$ is symmetric please?

Comment: @echo That is by assumption. Its existence is given by a theorem in the textbook I have.

Comment: Is the proof short? If so, could you please add it to your answer. I'm really interested in it.

Comment: @echo Unfortunately not. I can give you the basic sketch here. For any symmetric matrix $A$, there exists a diagonal matrix $D(\lambda_i) = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1  &  &  \\
 & \ddots &  \\
 &  & \lambda_n
\end{bmatrix}$ such that $A = PD(\lambda_i)P^{\prime}$ for $P$ orthogonal, which is the SVD of $A$. Set $G = PD(\gamma_i)P^{\prime}$ where $$\gamma_i = \begin{cases}
1/\lambda_i, & \lambda_i \neq 0 \\
0, & \lambda_i = 0\text{,}
\end{cases}$$ and compute $AGA$.

Comment: But is $G$ the unique generalized inverse?

Comment: @echo Of course not, but - it is *a* generalized inverse that is symmetric.

Comment: My doubt is that whether there is some other generalized inverse that is not symmetric. Your current proof would fail if this is the case. You question, if I understand correctly, asks for a proof for all possible generalized inverses.

Comment: @echo Sorry, I forgot to mention another part of the proof. There is a lemma that says that if $G$, $H$ are two generalized inverses, $XGX^{\prime} = XHX^{\prime}$ (a bit involved), so that since $X^{\prime}X$ is symmetric, then it has a generalized inverse that is symmetric. For this particular generalized inverse, say $\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-}$, $X\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-}X^{\prime}$ is symmetric, so that $X\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-}X^{\prime} = XGX^{\prime}$ is symmetric for any generalized inverse $G$ of $X^{\prime}X$.

Comment: Good. Make sense now. :)

Answer (score 2):

By a unitary changes of bases (note the plural form here --- $X$ in general is rectangular and we view it as a linear transformation between two vector spaces of possibly different dimensions) or singular value decomposition, you may assume that $X=\pmatrix{D&0\\ 0&0}$ where $D$ is a real invertible diagonal matrix. Then $X'X=\pmatrix{D^2&0\\ 0&0}$. It follows that any generalised inverse of $X'X$ must be in the form of $\pmatrix{D^{-2}&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}$. Hence
$$
X(X'X)^-X' = \pmatrix{I&0\\ 0&0},
$$
which is Hermitian. So it is Hermitian with respect to the original bases too, and it is real symmetric when $X$ is real.